# How to get the original values of an entire strongly typed DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kd9zhee%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it's possible to get the original version for a *single* column in a `DataRow`. However, this requires either using the column index or column name. This is a strongly-type dataset and I don't want to get into the maintainability nightmare of using magic column index numbers or string literals to specify which column I need.

Is there any way to get the entire strongly-typed row? Or, if that is not possible, is there a way to get a single strongly-typed column using a strongly-typed referenced?

Comment: I don't understand what you want by this:  `get a single strongly-typed column using a strongly-typed reference`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: A way to get the value without using a column index or a string literal. Ideally, some sort of column identifier that would be automatically updated if/when the column is changed in the designer. By strongly-typed column, I mean the column's value without having to cast to its true data type.

Comment: You are going to have to give the program some notion of which column you want... this means you will need to specify an index or name.  Don't think there is really a way around that.

Comment: @Evanlewis: I was hoping that the designer-generated code would provide some generated methods for getting at this. Just like does for accessing tables in dataset and strongly-type rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you will likely strike out across the board here.  The difference between the `Original` and `Modified` RowVersion only exists until `AcceptChanges()` is called...a finite period.  And the `Columns` collection at its heart is an `ArrayList`, with these accessors:

```
public DataColumn this[int index] { get; }
public DataColumn this[string name] { get; }
```

I don't see how you'd find a `DataColumn` any other way.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the getters don't allow this. It would have been nice if the designer code generator had automatically getters for each column in the table.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I know the post is old but I am looking for the difference (before acceptchanges is called) "The difference between the Original and Modified RowVersion only exists until AcceptChanges()" Yes that is what I would like - wish you had posted that answer too! I want the whole row not a column by column iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Example of single strongly-typed column using a strongly-typed reference:

```
// DataTable...
SkZapDataSet.vdSkZapDocumentDataTable dt
    = args.Row.Table as vdSkZapDocumentDataTable;
// DataRow...
SkZapDataSet.vdSkZapDocumentRow dr
    = args.Row as SkZapDataSet.vdSkZapDocumentRow;
// Value...
int id = (int)dr[dt.DocumentIdColumn.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original];
```